# Can't understand previous tick aggregation with "aggregatePrice" from highfrequency package?

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the function "aggregatePrice" from the [highfrequency](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/highfrequency/highfrequency.pdf). Let

```
2008-01-04 09:30:27 "193.71" 
2008-01-04 09:30:28 "193.59" 
2008-01-04 09:30:29 "193.445"
2008-01-04 09:30:30 "193.38" 
2008-01-04 09:30:31 "193.34" 
2008-01-04 09:30:33 "193.52" 
2008-01-04 09:30:34 "193.58" 
2008-01-04 09:30:35 "193.63" 
2008-01-04 09:30:36 "193.47" 
2008-01-04 09:30:37 "193.26" 
2008-01-04 09:30:38 "193.26" 
2008-01-04 09:30:39 "193.23" 
2008-01-04 09:30:40 "193.15" 
2008-01-04 09:30:41 "193.16" 
2008-01-04 09:30:46 "192.86" 
2008-01-04 09:30:47 "192.85" 
2008-01-04 09:30:49 "192.83" 
2008-01-04 09:30:50 "193"    
2008-01-04 09:30:51 "192.985"
2008-01-04 09:30:54 "193.045"
2008-01-04 09:30:56 "192.735"
2008-01-04 09:30:57 "192.85" 
2008-01-04 09:30:59 "192.68" 
2008-01-04 09:31:01 "192.99" 
2008-01-04 09:31:02 "192.795"
2008-01-04 09:31:03 "192.69" 
2008-01-04 09:31:05 "193.02" 
2008-01-04 09:31:07 "193.47" 
2008-01-04 09:31:10 "192.99" 
2008-01-04 09:31:12 "192.89"
```

be the raw data and

```
2008-01-04 09:30:00 193.710
2008-01-04 09:30:36 193.470
2008-01-04 09:30:45 193.160
2008-01-04 09:30:54 193.045
2008-01-04 09:31:03 192.690
2008-01-04 09:31:12 192.890
```

the 9-seconds aggregated data.

According to the manual by default previous tick aggregation is done. In case of previous tick aggregation, for on="seconds"/"minutes"/"hours", the element of the returned series with e.g. timestamp `09:35:00` contains the last observation up to that point, excluding the value at `09:35:00` itself. An exception is marketclose (i.e. `16:00:00` ET by default), where the observation at `16:00:00` is included in the interval, since this is the end of a trading day at the NYSE.

**My question is:** 
Why the aggregated data gives `2008-01-04 09:30:36 193.470` and not 
`2008-01-04 09:30:36 193.63`. The element of the returned series with timestamp `09:30:36` contains the last observation up to that point, excluding the value at `09:30:36` itself so the price shouldn't be `193.63`?

Please, maybe this is very simple for you but I really don't understand it.

The commands are:

```
#load data
data("sample_tdata");
#aggregate price data to the 30 second frequency
head(sample_tdata$PRICE)
head(aggregatePrice(sample_tdata$PRICE,on="secs",k=9));
```